# Camera stop working on Lenovo Yoga 510

Tags: release-juno, camera

my webcam has stopped working. I use Elementary Juno in Lenovo Yoga 510 and the message is that no supported camera was found.
However, when I open Skype the webcam works normally.
How do I proceed?

Comment: Unfortunately I have no solution. I have the same issue with camera app. Laptop is Dell Latitude-E7440.

Comment: Maybe you should report this issue to elementary OS developers: https://github.com/elementary/camera/issues